# Tried to make C Program Menu Option, but the code is running on loop

Tags: c

```
int main() 
{
    int choice;
    printf("Enter the size of array: ");     
    scanf("%d", &size); 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    { 
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]); 
    }    
    do 
    { 
        printf("\n******** Main Menu ********\n"); 
        printf("1. Display\n");         
        printf("2. Sort\n");         
        printf("3. Reverse\n");         
        printf("4. Search\n");         
        printf("5. Exit\n");         
        printf("Enter Your Choice: ");         
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice) 
        {
        case 1:
            display(size);
            break;
        case 2:
            sort(size);
            break;
        case 3:
            reverse(size);
            break;
        case 4:
        printf("Enter the value to search: ");
        scanf("%d", &val);
        search(val, size);
        break;
        case 5:
        break;
default:
printf("Invalid Choice\n");
break;
        }
     } while (choice != 5);
        return 0;
}
```

I was expecting it to show 4 choices and I do the user input, but its running on loop with input 'Invalid Choice'. This is just the part of long code.

Comment: Where is `size` declared? If it is a global, there's no point passing it as a parameter... Is it declared? Why does the code not verify the return value from `scanf()`?

Comment: See [mcve] . . .

Comment: Please edit the code and fix the formatting.

Comment: Your program doesn't even compile.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your program doesn't compile due to missing function and variable definitions, and it's also missing includes.

When you ask `scanf("%d", &choice)` to read an integer but pass something else, like 'a', it will fail, not set `choice` and it will also leave the unexpected input in the buffer.  Below I handle the failure by giving setting `choice = 0` which is invalid input, and flush the unexpected data from the input buffer.  As we only have 5 valid choices use a `char choice`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void display(size_t size) {
    printf("display\n");
}

void reverse(size_t size) {
    printf("reverse\n");
}

void search(int val, size_t size) {
    printf("search\n");
}

void sort(size_t size) {
    printf("sort\n");
}

void flush() {
    for(;;) {
        switch(getchar()) {
            case EOF:
            case '\n':
                return;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("Enter the size of array: ");
    size_t size;
    if(scanf("%zu", &size) != 1 || !size) {
        printf("invalid size\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int arr[size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if(scanf("%d", &arr[i]) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }

    char choice;
    do {
        printf("\n******** Main Menu ********\n");
        printf("1. Display\n");
        printf("2. Sort\n");
        printf("3. Reverse\n");
        printf("4. Search\n");
        printf("5. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter Your Choice: ");
        choice = 0;
        scanf("%hhd", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                display(size);
                break;
            case 2:
                sort(size);
                break;
            case 3:
                reverse(size);
                break;
            case 4: {
                printf("Enter the value to search: ");
                int val;
                if(scanf("%d", &val) != 1) {
                     printf("invalid val\n");
                     return 1;
                }
                search(val, size);
                break;
            }
            case 5:
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid Choice\n");
                break;
        }
        flush();
    } while (choice != 5);
    return 0;
}
```

sample session:

```
Enter the size of array: 3
1
2
3

******** Main Menu ********
1. Display
2. Sort
3. Reverse
4. Search
5. Exit
Enter Your Choice: 1
display

******** Main Menu ********
1. Display
2. Sort
3. Reverse
4. Search
5. Exit
Enter Your Choice: x
Invalid Choice

******** Main Menu ********
1. Display
2. Sort
3. Reverse
4. Search
5. Exit
Enter Your Choice: 5
```